# menu item call from tpl file

Tags: theming, routes

I have create one form in .tpl file with simple html form tag. 
In action attribute of this form element i passed a url like `'action=savequestion'`. Now in my .module file, inside hook_menu(), I am defining menu with the above url mentioned in action.

```
$items['savequestion'] = array(......); //like this
```

But when i am submitting that form defined in tpl file, It is not calling this menu item and page not found comes.

any one have idea about this? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you creating form in .tpl file. Rather than create it in your module file where you has created a menu item.

Comment: OK. I have created this in tpl. Because i don't want any extra field provided by drupal out of box. So.

Comment: I got a solution, I was on right way, I just forgot to add `'type' => 'MENU_CALLBACK'`

Comment: But it's right to create your form into module form. After creating into module file you can call it any where.

Comment: Ya WaQar. Agree.

Comment: Please explain why exactly do you have to use a template file here and why you can't build a custom module with a proper form inside?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this if you are using a Drupal module is to set up a form using the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) and process things within the context of a module. You can also use a contributed module such as [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) to accomplish this too, but if you want something really custom, you should not just create a form in a template file.

All of this said, make sure your "action" is set to the same path as your menu item and that after you have created your hook_menu entry you clear the cache, so your menu item becomes part of Drupal's menu registry.

Comment: This is very basic way, This won't fulfill according my requirements.  According to the flow, I need only one way to implement it. So i have to have follow this method.

Comment: Neither Form API nor Webform is basic.

Comment: Form API isn't basic  i agree and i understand. What i want to convey in above comment is, We can built form using admin, I have to have built this from backend and with just one filed.